# how to open ws protocol in nginx server?

Tags: nginx, websocket

I have simple chat server runs on socket.ibrahimyilmaz.me(I changed tornado websocket example) and in my local i can reach my server ws://127.0.0.1:8888 but in production environment, I can only reach over http but I want to be able to use ws protocol on nginx server.

Answer (score 1):

```
http {
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ''      close;
    }

    server {
        # the usual stuff...

        location /chat/ {
            proxy_pass http://backend;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        }
    }
```

Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html